# not accessing wildcard subdomain folder

Tags: mod-rewrite, subdomain, wildcard, http-host

when I am trying to load the wildcard subdomain its properly pointing the index file which I mentioned in the root domain .htaccess file like below

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*).mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*)  /mydomainfolder/index.php?username=%1

calling url us whatever.mysomain.com > its loading mydomainfolder/index.php properly

but I need to load a sub folder of the wildcard subdomain like below

whatever.mysomain.com/myproject 
by calling which I want to load mydomainfolder/myproject/index.php

but its still loading the mydomainfolder/index.php by calling the above. How this can be solved? Its a godaddy server with shared hosting.

Comment: Could you improve your formatting a bit? Capitalization, etc. This is not a chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Go Daddy shared hosting does not support wildcard the setup of wildcard subdomains.  However, if you have a dedicated IP on your shared hosting account and the domain is the primary domain on the account, you can then add a wildcard DNS record for the domain that points to your shared hosting account's dedicated IP address.